# Fix Section when reaches top. Unfix when previous section is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to stick a `section` to the top when it hits the top of the browser on scroll down, but I'd like to unstick it when the user scrolls back up and the previous `section` is back in view.

I'm detecting distance from top to `section` I'd like to stick, but once its at the top how do we detect user scrolling back up and previous `section` comes back into view.

My Codepen: https://codepen.io/omarel/pen/LeEjax

**Snippet**

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  sectionone = $('section.one').offset().top;
  sectiontwo = $('section.two').offset().top;
  sectiontwodistance = (sectiontwo - scrollTop);
  sectiononedistance = (sectionone - scrollTop);
  console.log(sectiononedistance);
  if (sectiontwodistance < 1) {
    $('section.two').addClass('fix');
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

section {
  height: 100%;
  border: 5px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

section.one {
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0%;
}

section.two {
  border: 5px solid green;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 100%;
}

section.three {
  z-index: 3;
  top: 200%;
}

section.fix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="one">
  1
</section>

<section class="two">
  2
</section>

<section class="three">
  3
</section>
```

Comment: You say "Fix `<div>`" yet you have no divs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would update your jQuery to the snippet below. It checks the position of section one against the height of the window and if less than, or equal to it removes the `.fix` class.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  sectionone = $('section.one').offset().top;
  sectiontwo = $('section.two').offset().top;
  sectiontwodistance = (sectiontwo - scrollTop);
  sectiononedistance = (sectionone - scrollTop);
  console.log(sectiononedistance);
  if (sectiontwodistance < 1) {
    $('section.two').addClass('fix');
  }

  if (Math.abs(sectiononedistance) <= $(window).height()) {
    $('section.two').removeClass('fix');
  }
});
```